# Django - How to properly handle routes and redirect in CRUD App

Tags: django

I have a small app which has index/view/create/delete/store appointment functions.

For my store function which simply adds a new appointment entry to database, how do i handle the url so there is no need for /store. I think im looking for a way to define strictly whether the routes are a get/post/delete.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "appointments"

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('<int:appointment_id>/', views.detail, name="detail"),
    path('create/', views.create, name="create"),
    path('store/', views.store, name="store"),
    path('<int:appointment_id>/', views.delete, name="delete"),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Appointment

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    appointments = Appointment.objects.all()

    context = {
        'appointments': appointments
    }

    return render(request, 'appointments/index.html', context)

def detail(request, appointment_id):

    appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, pk=appointment_id)

    context = {
        'appointment': appointment
    }

    return render(request, 'appointments/detail.html', context)

def create(request):
    return render(request, 'appointments/create.html')

def store(request):

    make = request.POST['make']
    model = request.POST['model']
    description = request.POST['description']
    date_time = request.POST['date_time']

    appointment = Appointment(make=make, model=model, description=description, date_time=date_time)
    appointment.save()

    return redirect('/appointments')

def delete(request, appointment_id):

    appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, pk=appointment_id)
    appointment.delete()

    return redirect('/appointments')
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why don't you want /store? What else would be responsible for creating entries? (And why do you have a separate /create that doesn't do anything?)

Comment: @DanielRoseman my create is there to just render the page that contains the form. When the form is submitted it posts to /store. Perhaps i'm not following the standard convention then? I wanted a place to post somewhere without it actually being a link.